# I have a problem with npm package nexe and visual studio, trying to convert a nodejs app in an .exe

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, nexe

`nexe` is a npm package to convert nodejs apps to an .exe, but I have a problem when I run

`nexe --build index.js`

so I add `--verbose` and this is the message:

[image: terminal]

the message said: **failed to find a suitable Visual studio installation** and also **vcbuild.bat nosign release x64 exited with code: 1**

#### My question is:

is it mandatory to have visual studio installed? I read that "desktop development with c++" is necessary to make the .exe in windows. BUT:

[image: visual studio]

I make this question because my internet connection is so bad, and the visual studio installation will take me 4 or 5 days, because it's a little bit more of 7gb. Is there a lighter alternative that has the necessary packages?

**NOTE:** I make this question here in stackoverflow because I open a issue in the nexe github repo and nobody answered me. So i hope someone tried that package and if they got the same error tell me what they did to fix it

**NOTE 2:** I also tried `pkg` for vercel, but also have problems making an .exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described here ([gitanswer.com](https://gitanswer.com/nexe-vcbuild-bat-nosign-release-x64-exited-with-code-1-typescript-665804799)) this is indeed necessary for making nexe finally work. In my case it was the solution.
I installed VS 2022 and added the marked workload additionally.

I ran nexe-4.0.0-beta-19 on Windows.

First I had to install NSAM from here ([nasm.us](https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.15.04/win64/)) and Python (3.10 using chocolatey in my case).